# Email not sending in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

when i am using

```
    MAIL_MAILER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx
    MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxx
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxx
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

so it is giving this error

Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Network is unreachable)

while when i am using

```
    MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx
    MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxx
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxxxxx
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

so then error is not showing but email is not receiving on the other hand so please anyone help me here in this issue that where i am doing the error

Controller code is

```
         Mail::send('email.username_email',['data'=>$data],function ($message){
            $message->from("xxxxx", "HCML Lab");
            $message->subject('UserName Change');
            $message->to("xxxxxx");
        });
```

Comment: Are you using your password or an app-code in MAIL_PASSWORD?

Comment: I am using the app password which i get after making an app and get password after on two step varification